# TypeError:a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when reading from a file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte, file-handling

I am trying to use the dataset from file to implement my project in ML

```
authors_file_handler = open(authors_file, "r")
authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)
authors_file_handler.close()
```

After this I am getting error in this line

> authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: In which line are you getting the error? Please provide full traceback.

Comment: Try:`authors = pickle.load(bytes(authors_file_handler,encoding="utf-8"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary reading mode:

```
authors_file_handler = open(authors_file, "rb") # Note the added 'b'
authors = pickle.load(authors_file_handler)
authors_file_handler.close()
```

From the `pickle.load()` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

> The argument file must have two methods, a read() method that takes an
>   integer argument, and a readline() method that requires no arguments.
>   Both methods should return bytes. Thus file can be an on-disk file
>   **opened for binary reading**, an io.BytesIO object, or any other custom
>   object that meets this interface.